# Ruby on Rails - Model definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oop, activerecord

I am currently learning Ruby on Rails and there's a thing I don't understand why it is like that, and also how.

Let's say we have a `users` table with this structure:

```
+-------+---------------+
| id    | int(11)       |
| name  | varchar(255)  |
+-------+---------------+
```

Why the model file only looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Model
end
```

There's no property neither getter/setter.

- How is that working?
- Why is it like this?
- Would I need `attr_accessor :id, :username`?

I have a big background in PHP and C# and I've never seen that. I bet I'm not the only one how asked himself on this, so sorry if it's a duplicate (I searched but found nothing)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works more or less like this:
First time your user-class is called, it looks for a table with the name `users`. If it exists, it will load all fields from this table, "automagically" creating "setters" and "getters" for you.

E.g., you will have out of the box:

```
user = User.new
user.name
user.name=
user.name? # which will tell you if this field is nil, or not.
```

and things like

```
User.find_by_name('name')
```

Also, you can "check" your class in console, like this:

```
rails c # or irb, but I don't know how much you'd have to require then ...

User # and just hit enter
```

it will produce something like:

```
User(id: number, name: string)
```

Comment: Ok, but is this not a bottleneck due to the `EXPLAIN` query I guess?

Comment: It should not create an explain. If it does, just by looking up the fields of the table, there probably is something quite broken/wrong configured/slow connection within the system. Or do you mean something else? Also, it usually does this only once ...

Comment: I guess it does this lookup on initialization of the apps, or every request in dev mode. But how it can lookup the fields in a table without an EXPLAIN or something else that list the table structure?

Comment: I think Rails loads your database schema when the application server is started. I believe this would provide it with the table structure. See the `db` folder in your Rails project.

Comment: Good point! So if I understand correctly, the only place where my column names or important is in the migrations file and the `schema.rb` right? So everything else (except filtered params I know) will update itself with new structure.

Comment: You probably mean a DESCRIBE? I've just added an explanation, how you can have an 'insight' into your model.

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux: migrations and schema.rb are important, but the authoritative source of the schema is the database. When rails app boots up, it reads the database schema and generates corresponding model methods. If a field is in a migration, but not in the db, rails won't see it (problem of the forgotten migration)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks!

Comment: @AndreasGnyp To address the comment in your code, the `rails c` command loads your entire Rails environment, so for the vast majority of cases you don't need any `require` statements.

Comment: @Alexander yes, of course. I meant, if you have to use _irb_, instead of _rails c_ I wouldn't know out of the box, what you'd have to require to let activerecord work.